# Analyzing the distribution of data in HBase - hotspotting check

Tags: java, hbase, hdfs, nosql

I want to make sure that my HBase table does not suffer from hotspotting.

My first approach was to run the following command:

```
hdfs dfs -du -h /hbase/my_table/
```

and take a look at the data size on disk by region. However, this approach might suffer from incoming data size changing over time and varying compression ratio depending on the data.

Would it make sense to count the number of rows handled by each regionserver? Is there a command or some specific configuration of RowCounter to quickly do that?

Anything else that I'm missing out?